# Resizing elements but keeping centralised

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making some breadcrumbs and restricting the width of them using `text-overflow` so the text does not spill over. I have wrote a jQuery script which enlarges the size of the breadcrumb when the user hovers over it.

My problem is that when the breadcrumb is enlarged, they end up too long to fit inside the container. I need to make the width of the other breadcrumbs smaller and at the same time, make the highlighted breadcrumb longer.

I have wrote a script for this but it is very buggy. The reason is that when other breadcrumbs are shrunk down in size, the position of the highlighted breadcrumb moves.

I would like the highlighted breadcrumb to expand in size *outwards*, so that it remains in the same position. But the breadcrumbs around it shrink in size to allow everything to fit on.

Is this do-able?

Here's a fiddle of what I've got so far-
http://jsfiddle.net/8FPeS/

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.breadcrumbButton').mouseenter(function(){

    $('.breadcrumbButton').css({width:'30px', minWidth:'30px'});
    $(this).css({width:'auto', minWidth:'80px'});

});


$('.breadcrumbButton').mouseleave(function(){

    $('.breadcrumbButton').css({width:'80px', minWidth:'80px'});
    $(this).css({width:'80px'});

});
```

Comment: If you shrink the other breadcrumbs the breadcrumb you're on can't stay in the same place, unless you mean you want to change padding? Also hi.

Comment: Hey @BeatAlex Yeah, I guess it's the padding I want to change. I've just found a jQuery plug-in for it - http://www.ajaxblender.com/script-sources/xbreadcrumbs/demo/ The second one down is exactly what I want but I'd rather code it myself than use a plug-in. Any idea how it works?

Comment: I'll try and whip something up but first I'm sorting out your css. You have a lot of unnecessary rules you're re-doing lol.

Comment: Your names for stuff is crazy too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-coded it from scratch to hopefully get it to work to [<kbd>Codepen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/Iyhcm)/[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrf22/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="container">
  <li><a href="#">Network Accessories</a>
  <li><a href="#">DYMO</a>
  <li><a href="#">Labelling Solutions</a>
  <li><a href="#">Labelling Solutions</a>
  <li><a href="#">Sound Proof Data Cabinets & Server Racks</a>
  <li><a href="#">Labelling Solutions</a>
  <li class='active'><a href="#">Dymo Flexible Nylon</a>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
    width: 735px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#container li:first-child {
    margin-left: -20px;
}

#container li {
    margin-right: 22px;
    background: #eee;
    border-right: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 18px 0 17px 17px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #eee;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -17px;
}

li:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 18px 0 18px 18px;
    border-color: #eee #eee #eee transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -18px;
}

#container li a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    max-width: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.active {
    background: #333365 !important;
}

.active:before {
    border-color: #333365 #333365 #333365 transparent;
}

.active:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #333365;
}

.active a {
    max-width: 1000px;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.hover {
    max-width: 1000px !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('li').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.active a').css('max-width', '40px');
  $(this).children('a').addClass('hover');
});

$('li').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).children('a').removeClass('hover');
  $('.active a').css('max-width', '1000px');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @DanielJohnson yw bbz xxx